# How To Disable Button if CheckBox is unchecked with If Statement in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox

```
    private void btnAddTopping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        {
            if((chbGarlic.Checked)  || (chbGreenPepper.Checked) || 
                  (chbMashroom.Checked) || (chbOnion.Checked) || 
                  (chbOnion.Checked)||(chbOlives.Checked) ||
                  (chbCreamCheese.Checked) || (chbCheddar.Checked) || 
                  (chbCheddar.Checked)||(chbFettaCheese.Checked) || 
                    (chbChicken.Checked) || (chbGroundBeef.Checked) )   
                PriceForHotSubTopping = 8.99;
```

this is my code. Now i want to Disable the btnAddTopping, till check box is unchecked. what can i do most now ??

Comment: This code is already inside the Click() event, so it would never run if the button was disabled?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `LINQ` extension for the finding all the checkboxes, like this:

```
this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Any(chb => chb.Checked);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event handler for CheckBoxName.CheckedChanged Event and type

```
btnAddTopping.Enabled = CheckBoxName.Checked;
```

Comment: UncheckedChanged event should also be used in your scenario to disable `IsEnabled` property of the button when the check box is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Let me share with you an elegant XAML solution, without even having to use code-behind scenario:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkBox" Content="Check me" />
<Button x:Name="btnAddTopping" Content="Click me" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkBox, Path=IsChecked}" />
```

Using this approach, `IsEnabled` property of the `Button` gets bound to the `IsChecked` property of the `CheckBox` and you don't even have to apply code behind logic.

Hope I've helped!

Comment: Did you saw how many such checkboxes user have? Yes, his design is quite bad, but still your approach seems not very applycable for him.